# What @Query to make MongoRepository ignore blank parameters?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have this query interface:

```
public interface IMyDocDao extends MongoRepository<MyDoc, String> {

   @Query(value = "{ 'stuff.in.nested.doc' : ?0, 'another.stuff.in.nested.doc' : ?1 }")
   List<MyDoc> findByFoo(String foo, String bar);
}
```

If a call `findByFoo("a", "b")` it works correctly.

If a call `findByFoo("", "b")` it returns the documents for which the first parameter is blank and the second one is "b".

If a call `findByFoo(null, "b")` it returns the documents for which there is no property `stuff.in.nested.doc` and the second one is "b".

Is there a way to tell the query to ignore the parameter `foo` in case it is blank/empty ?

In other words, I would like `findByFoo("", "b")` to simply return all the documents for which the parameter `bar` is "b", ignoring the first parameter.

As the number of parameters may increase, writing multiple methods is not a scalable option.

Comment: Why would you want that? Just make a second method `findAll`. If you need more dynamic queries, you may have to write your own code for that. Maybe like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151977/mongorepository-dynamic-queries?rq=1

Comment: Here I've simplified the code, actually there is more than one parameter. I'll edit the question.

Comment: [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) allows querying with a variable number of parameters (by default, null parameters are ignored for the query). You can configure the behavior (e.g. ignore empty strings, or [more complex behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647967/5873923)) for any given parameter with [QuerydslBindings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl./binding/QuerydslBindings.html).

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple solution that works is to use a custom repository implementation as described [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-mongodb-example/). For my sample code it would give:

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Override
public List<MyDoc> findByCriteria(Map<String, String> requestCriteria) {

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Foo
    if (requestCriteria.containsKey("foo")) {
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(requestCriteria.get("foo"))) {
            criteria = criteria.and("stuff.in.nested.doc").is(requestCriteria.get("foo"));
        }
    }

    // Bar
    if (requestCriteria.containsKey("bar")) {
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(requestCriteria.get("bar"))) {
            criteria = criteria.and("another.stuff.in.nested.doc").is(requestCriteria.get("bar"));
        }
    }

    return mongoTemplate.find(new Query(criteria), MyDoc.class, "mydoc");
}
```

Another solution could be using [QueryDSL](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-mongodb) (from [Marc Tarin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5873923/marc-tarin)'s comment), I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Your solution is fine when there is a few parameters to cover, but here the main advantage of using QueryDSL is that the wanted behavior can be set for all String parameters at once (which also means no change to the repository when the domain object is added a new member).

Answer (score 0):

A quickly crafted solution with QueryDSL:

```
public interface IMyDocDao extends MongoRepository<MyDoc, String>,
                                   QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyDoc>, 
                                   QuerydslBinderCustomizer<MyDoc> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QMyDoc myDoc) { // QMyDoc is generated by QueryDSL at build time
        bindings.bind(MyDoc.class)
                .first((StringPath path, String value) -> { 
                   if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                       path.eq(value);
                   }
                });
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, inject an IMyDocDao:

```
@RestController
public class MyDocController {

    @Autowire
    private IMyDocDao myDocDao;

    @GetMapping("myDoc/search/query")
    public List<MyDoc> query(@QuerydslPredicate(root = MyDoc.class) Predicate predicate) {
        return myDocDao(predicate);
}
```

`GET .../myDoc/search/query?stuff.in.nested.doc=a&another.stuff.in.nested.doc=b` should return the expected result (haven't tested it, though).

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep my solution for now as it feed my requirements. I'll try QueryDSL if some day I come to limitations by using mongoTemplate-based custom repo.